# What's the best way to render multiple views in the same template?

Tags: django

**Scenario**

I need to render 2 separate views from a third party app, in the same View. The views in question are for login and signup.

The template for each view then simply includes an inclusion tag to render a generic form.

**Solution**

The solution i've come up with is to register a tag for each view that creates a `template.Node` to render each one.

```
from django import template

from third_party_app import LoginView, SignupView

register = template.Library()

@register.tag
def login_form(parser, token):
    return ViewNode(LoginView, template_name=get_template_name(token))

@register.tag
def signup_form(parser, token):
    return ViewNode(SignupView, template_name=get_template_name(token))


class ViewNode(template.Node):

    def __init__(self, view_class, **kwargs):
        self.view_class = view_class
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def render(self, context):
        request = context['request']
        self.kwargs['request'] = request
        view = self.view_class(**self.kwargs)
        response = view.get(request)
        response.render()
        return response.content


def get_template_name(token):
    tag_name, template = token.split_contents()
    return str(template[1:-1])
```

And the template for the main View looks like this:

```
<div>

    {% login_form 'account/login.html' %}

</div>

... some other html ...

<div>

    {% signup_form 'account/signup.html' %}

</div>
```

The template for each of the individual login and signup views only contains an inclusion tag to render another template for a generic form.

So accounts/login.html is simply this:

```
{% render_login_form %}
```

and the inclusion tag looks like this

```
@register.inclusion_tag('account/snippets/form.html', takes_context=True)
def render_login_form(context):
    return {'form': context['form'],
            'primary_btn_label': 'Sign In',
            'secondary_btn_label': 'Forgot Password?',
            'tertiary_btn_label': 'Sign Up?',
            'col_offset': '3',
            'col_width': '9'}
```

**Question**

It works, but i'm wondering 2 things.

1. Is this the best way to render 2 Views in the same View?
2. It feels like there are two many steps to achieve this. Is there a simpler way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have does something similar this way:

First two templates `login.html` and `signup.html`. In these templates I access context variables like `form`, `primary_btn_label` and other stuff you have in your `render_login_form` inclusion tag.

But then I have a custom context processor (See the Django documentation on [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)) that initializes these variables (like `form` and so on)

The context processor (save in `myapp/context_processors.py`) looks something like this:

```
from .forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm

def login_register_form(request):
    login_popup_form = LoginFormForPopup()
    register_popup_form = RegisterFormForPopup()
    context = {
        'login_popup_form': login_popup_form,
        'register_popup_form': register_popup_form,
    }

    return context
```

The custom context processor is enabled in your Django settings file by adding it to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'myapp.context_processors.login_register_form',
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Anton. That's not far off what i started with, but decided against it, as the views also have context data and initial values that are used to render the template. So it started to feel like there was too much duplication, when a View already existed that did the same job.